# adding constraints to navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift

I need to implement this design in my app, but I can't figure out a way to add this constraint to the navigation bar.

I tried adding the constraint to top layout guide with a negative offset, but the navigation bar is always on top

[image]

Is there a way to use NSLayoutconstraints to create this specific layout with the navigation bar?

Comment: I tried adding the constraint to top layout guide with a negative offset, but the navigation bar is always on top

Comment: Then please add that to your question

Comment: It's not a constraint issue, it's a "z" layer issue. Worse, I'm unsure if you can do this. A "stock" UINavigationController is meant to always be on top. I seem to recall another question in the last week asking something similar, and the answer was to place the top-most view above the navigation controller in AppDelegate.swift. I do realize this isn't much help, but hopefully I'm pointing you in a direction. Negative constraints may help some, but not with the true issue.

Comment: thanks dfd, I will give it a try

Comment: You could try adding this view as a title view to the `UINavigationBar` with appropriate offsets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this design,you can put your button on your window view by the code below.

```
UIWindow *appWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[aButton setFrame:CGRectMake((appWindow.frame.size.width/2)-35, 20, 70, 100)];
[appWindow addSubview:aButton];
```

In addition,you can also use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]
```

to get the window

Answer (score 0):

Henson Fang answer in **Swift 4.2** :

```
func configNavigationTitle() {
    let groupImageView = UIImageView()
    groupImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    groupImageView.image = R.image.groupMenu()

    let titleLable = UILabel()
    titleLable.textColor = .white
    titleLable.textAlignment = .center
    titleLable.font = R.font.iranSansMobile(size: 17)
    titleLable.text = title
    titleLable.sizeToFit()

    let backView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    titleLable.frame = CGRect(x: backView.frame.size.width / 2 - titleLable.frame.size.width / 2, y: -20, width: titleLable.frame.size.width, height: titleLable.frame.size.height)
    backView.addSubview(titleLable)
    navigationItem.titleView = backView

    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    groupImageView.frame = CGRect(x: (window?.frame.size.width)! / 2 - 20, y: 45, width: 40, height: 40)
    window?.addSubview(groupImageView)
}
```